# "Unclear what you're asking" votes with accepted answers

Tags: discussion

Should there be some additional guidelines for "Unclear what you're asking" flags?  Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457653/gsub-gsub-gsub-gsub-localhost-thats).  After two answers, one of which was accepted, someone votes to close as "Unclear."

It makes me wonder if there should be some restriction on using "Unclear" when there are already existing answers.  Any thoughts on this?  If several other people seem to be able to understand the question clearly enough to formulate upvoted answers, wouldn't that tend to indicate that the question is clear enough?

Comment: this HAS to be a dupe.... I don't remember where, but I've seen this already asked. The base logic is that not EVERYONE understands it the same way, so even if someone makes an assumption and gets it right, the fact it's unclear means that no one else would search for that/ the fact it can attract very varied answers based on the assumptions

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Should I vote to close a question if it has an accepted answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193098) and additionally see [Do I need to read the answers when voting to close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227037)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying questions.  I hadn't searched for them in quite that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question with an answer doesn't necessarily make the question clear.

It could be, and is often the case that, when someone answers a question in that state, they're only answering it based on an incomplete assumption, or otherwise missing information.  Or worse, the OP has described an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248), and people are happily addressing a symptom of their choice as opposed to the actual problem.

In these circumstances, if you personally feel that the question is clear, edit it into shape to make it clearer.  Then, cast a reopen vote and see if others in the review queues agree.